# Hyperledger Composer Rest Servers on Separate Physical Machines

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have managed to install a hyperledger composer network on two separate physical machines where each machine has one user in separate organizations. I am able to start the rest server on the same peer as where I started the composer network, but am unable to start a rest server on the other peer.

When I issue

> composer-rest-server -c bob-org2@network -n never -w true

I get

> Connection fails: Error: Error trying to ping. Error: 2 UNKNOWN: error executing chaincode: could not get ChaincodeDeploymentSpec for *network*:0.0.1: get ChaincodeDeploymentSpec for *network*/mychannel from LSCC error: chaincode fingerprint mismatch data mismatch
>   It will be retried for the next request.
>   Exception: Error: Error trying to ping. Error: 2 UNKNOWN: error executing chaincode: could not get ChaincodeDeploymentSpec for *network*:0.0.1: get ChaincodeDeploymentSpec for *network*/mychannel from LSCC error: chaincode fingerprint mismatch data mismatch
>   Error: Error trying to ping. Error: 2 UNKNOWN: error executing chaincode: could not get ChaincodeDeploymentSpec for *network*:0.0.1: get ChaincodeDeploymentSpec for bl-security-network/mychannel from LSCC error: chaincode fingerprint mismatch data mismatch
>       at _checkRuntimeVersions.then.catch (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:787:34)
>       at

I see this should be possible based on this answer:

[How should composer setup to be done for hyperledger fabric network deployment for multiple orgs on multiple physical machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48280707/how-should-composer-setup-to-be-done-for-hyperledger-fabric-network-deployment-f)

I see errors in the docker container peer0.org1.example.com-peer0.org1.example.com-network-0.0.1

> bl-security-network@0.0.1 start /usr/local/src
>   start-network "--peer.address" "10.0.0.224:7052"
>
> running start.js E0510 07:49:44.580450529      17
>   ssl_transport_security.cc:238] Could not get common name of subject
>   from certificate. 2018-05-10T07:49:44.630Z [8d62931a] ERROR
>   :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object
>   with ID 'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.AssetRegistry' in
>   collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
>   2018-05-10T07:49:44.644Z [8d62931a] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection
>   :get()                     Error: Object with ID
>   'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' in
>   collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
>   2018-05-10T07:49:44.654Z [8d62931a] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection
>   :get()                     Error: Object with ID
>   'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.TransactionRegistry' in
>   collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
>   2018-05-10T07:49:44.663Z [8d62931a] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection
>   :get()                     Error: Object with ID
>   'Participant:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in
>   collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
>   2018-05-10T07:49:44.672Z [8d62931a] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection
>   :get()                     Error: Object with ID
>   'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.HistorianRecord' in collection
>   with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist 2018-05-10T07:49:44.681Z
>   [8d62931a] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()
>   Error: Object with ID
>   'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.AddAsset' in collection
>   with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist 2018-05-10T07:49:44.694Z
>   [8d62931a] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()
>   Error: Object with ID
>   'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.UpdateAsset' in
>   collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
>   2018-05-10T07:49:44.704Z [8d62931a] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection
>   :get()                     Error: Object with ID
>   'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.RemoveAsset' in
>   collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
>   2018-05-10T07:49:44.714Z [8d62931a] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection
>   :get()                     Error: Object with ID
>   'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.AddParticipant' in
>   collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
>   2018-05-10T07:49:44.723Z [8d62931a] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection
>   :get()                     Error: Object with ID
>   'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.UpdateParticipant' in
>   collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
>   2018-05-10T07:49:44.732Z [8d62931a] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection
>   :get()                     Error: Object with ID
>   'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.RemoveParticipant' in
>   collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
>   2018-05-10T07:49:44.747Z [8d62931a] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection
>   :get()                     Error: Object with ID
>   'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.Identity' in collection with ID
>   '$sysregistries' does not exist 2018-05-10T07:49:44.756Z [8d62931a]
>   ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error:
>   Object with ID
>   'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.IssueIdentity' in
>   collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
>   2018-05-10T07:49:44.765Z [8d62931a] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection
>   :get()                     Error: Object with ID
>   'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.BindIdentity' in
>   collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
>   2018-05-10T07:49:44.775Z [8d62931a] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection
>   :get()                     Error: Object with ID
>   'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ActivateCurrentIdentity'
>   in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
>   2018-05-10T07:49:44.784Z [8d62931a] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection
>   :get()                     Error: Object with ID
>   'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.RevokeIdentity' in
>   collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
>   2018-05-10T07:49:44.794Z [8d62931a] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection
>   :get()                     Error: Object with ID
>   'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.StartBusinessNetwork' in
>   collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
>   2018-05-10T07:49:44.805Z [8d62931a] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection
>   :get()                     Error: Object with ID
>   'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ResetBusinessNetwork' in
>   collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
>   2018-05-10T07:49:44.813Z [8d62931a] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection
>   :get()                     Error: Object with ID
>   'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.SetLogLevel' in
>   collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
>   2018-05-10T07:49:44.822Z [8d62931a] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection
>   :get()                     Error: Object with ID
>   'Participant:blil.security.FilePartic' in collection with ID
>   '$sysregistries' does not exist 2018-05-10T07:49:44.835Z [8d62931a]
>   ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error:
>   Object with ID 'Transaction:blil.security.addToLogFile' in collection
>   with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist 2018-05-10T07:49:44.852Z
>   [8d62931a] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()
>   Error: Object with ID 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin'
>   in collection with ID
>   'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' does not
>   exist 2018-05-10T07:49:44.852Z [8d62931a] ERROR    :Resolver
>   :resolveRelationship()     Failed to resolve relationship
>   {"stack":["{Error}Object with ID
>   'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in collection with ID
>   'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' does not
>   exist Error: Object with ID
>   'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in collection with ID
>   'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' does not
>   exist","    at NodeDataCollection.get
>   (/usr/local/src/node_modules/composer-runtime-hlfv1/lib/nodedatacollection.js:73:28)","
>   at ","    at process._tickCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)"]} 2018-05-10T07:49:44.854Z
>   [8d62931a] INFO     :IdentityManager          :()
>   Binding in the tx names and impl 2018-05-10T07:49:44.863Z [8d62931a]
>   INFO     :EngineTransactions       :createHistorianRecord()   created
>   historian record 2018-05-10T07:49:44.869Z [8d62931a] ERROR
>   :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object
>   with ID 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in collection
>   with ID 'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry'
>   does not exist 2018-05-10T07:49:44.869Z [8d62931a] ERROR    :Resolver 
>   :resolveRelationship()     Failed to resolve relationship
>   {"stack":["{Error}Object with ID
>   'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in collection with ID
>   'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' does not
>   exist Error: Object with ID
>   'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in collection with ID
>   'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' does not
>   exist","    at NodeDataCollection.get
>   (/usr/local/src/node_modules/composer-runtime-hlfv1/lib/nodedatacollection.js:73:28)","
>   at ","    at process._tickCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)"]} 2018-05-10T07:49:44.876Z
>   [8d62931a] INFO     :EngineTransactions       :createHistorianRecord()
>   created historian record 2018-05-10T07:49:44.888Z [8d62931a] ERROR
>   :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object
>   with ID 'alice-org1' in collection with ID
>   'Participant:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' does not
>   exist 2018-05-10T07:49:44.889Z [8d62931a] ERROR    :Resolver
>   :resolveRelationship()     Failed to resolve relationship
>   {"stack":["{Error}Object with ID 'alice-org1' in collection with ID
>   'Participant:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' does not
>   exist Error: Object with ID 'alice-org1' in collection with ID
>   'Participant:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' does not
>   exist","    at NodeDataCollection.get
>   (/usr/local/src/node_modules/composer-runtime-hlfv1/lib/nodedatacollection.js:73:28)","
>   at ","    at process._tickCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)"]} 2018-05-10T07:49:44.908Z
>   [8d62931a] INFO     :EngineTransactions       :createHistorianRecord()
>   created historian record 2018-05-10T07:49:44.914Z [8d62931a] ERROR
>   :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object
>   with ID 'bob-org2' in collection with ID
>   'Participant:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' does not
>   exist 2018-05-10T07:49:44.914Z [8d62931a] ERROR    :Resolver
>   :resolveRelationship()     Failed to resolve relationship
>   {"stack":["{Error}Object with ID 'bob-org2' in collection with ID
>   'Participant:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' does not
>   exist Error: Object with ID 'bob-org2' in collection with ID
>   'Participant:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' does not
>   exist","    at NodeDataCollection.get
>   (/usr/local/src/node_modules/composer-runtime-hlfv1/lib/nodedatacollection.js:73:28)","
>   at ","    at process._tickCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)"]} 2018-05-10T07:49:44.925Z
>   [8d62931a] INFO     :EngineTransactions       :createHistorianRecord()
>   created historian record 2018-05-10T07:49:44.932Z [8d62931a] ERROR
>   :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object
>   with ID 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in collection
>   with ID 'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry'
>   does not exist 2018-05-10T07:49:44.932Z [8d62931a] ERROR    :Resolver 
>   :resolveRelationship()     Failed to resolve relationship
>   {"stack":["{Error}Object with ID
>   'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in collection with ID
>   'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' does not
>   exist Error: Object with ID
>   'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in collection with ID
>   'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' does not
>   exist","    at NodeDataCollection.get
>   (/usr/local/src/node_modules/composer-runtime-hlfv1/lib/nodedatacollection.js:73:28)","
>   at ","    at process._tickCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)"]} 2018-05-10T07:49:44.935Z
>   [8d62931a] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()
>   Error: Object with ID 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin'
>   in collection with ID
>   'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' does not
>   exist 2018-05-10T07:49:44.935Z [8d62931a] ERROR    :Resolver
>   :resolveRelationship()     Failed to resolve relationship
>   {"stack":["{Error}Object with ID
>   'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in collection with ID
>   'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' does not
>   exist Error: Object with ID
>   'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in collection with ID
>   'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' does not
>   exist","    at NodeDataCollection.get
>   (/usr/local/src/node_modules/composer-runtime-hlfv1/lib/nodedatacollection.js:73:28)","
>   at ","    at process._tickCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)"]} 2018-05-10T07:49:44.939Z
>   [8d62931a] INFO     :EngineTransactions       :createHistorianRecord()
>   created historian record 2018-05-10T07:51:29.627Z [3ac15224] ERROR
>   :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object
>   with ID 'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.AssetRegistry' in
>   collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
>   2018-05-10T07:51:29.641Z [3ac15224] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection
>   :get()                     Error: Object with ID
>   'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' in
>   collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
>   2018-05-10T07:51:29.649Z [3ac15224] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection
>   :get()                     Error: Object with ID
>   'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.TransactionRegistry' in
>   collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
>   2018-05-10T07:51:29.657Z [3ac15224] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection
>   :get()                     Error: Object with ID
>   'Participant:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in
>   collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
>   2018-05-10T07:51:29.666Z [3ac15224] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection
>   :get()                     Error: Object with ID
>   'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.HistorianRecord' in collection
>   with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist 2018-05-10T07:51:29.675Z
>   [3ac15224] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()
>   Error: Object with ID
>   'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.AddAsset' in collection
>   with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist 2018-05-10T07:51:29.685Z
>   [3ac15224] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()
>   Error: Object with ID
>   'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.UpdateAsset' in
>   collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
>   2018-05-10T07:51:29.696Z [3ac15224] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection
>   :get()                     Error: Object with ID
>   'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.RemoveAsset' in
>   collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
>   2018-05-10T07:51:29.709Z [3ac15224] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection
>   :get()                     Error: Object with ID
>   'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.AddParticipant' in
>   collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
>   2018-05-10T07:51:29.718Z [3ac15224] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection
>   :get()                     Error: Object with ID
>   'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.UpdateParticipant' in
>   collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
>   2018-05-10T07:51:29.726Z [3ac15224] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection
>   :get()                     Error: Object with ID
>   'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.RemoveParticipant' in
>   collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
>   2018-05-10T07:51:29.734Z [3ac15224] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection
>   :get()                     Error: Object with ID
>   'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.Identity' in collection with ID
>   '$sysregistries' does not exist 2018-05-10T07:51:29.741Z [3ac15224]
>   ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error:
>   Object with ID
>   'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.IssueIdentity' in
>   collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
>   2018-05-10T07:51:29.750Z [3ac15224] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection
>   :get()                     Error: Object with ID
>   'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.BindIdentity' in
>   collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
>   2018-05-10T07:51:29.759Z [3ac15224] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection
>   :get()                     Error: Object with ID
>   'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ActivateCurrentIdentity'
>   in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
>   2018-05-10T07:51:29.766Z [3ac15224] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection
>   :get()                     Error: Object with ID
>   'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.RevokeIdentity' in
>   collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
>   2018-05-10T07:51:29.773Z [3ac15224] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection
>   :get()                     Error: Object with ID
>   'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.StartBusinessNetwork' in
>   collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
>   2018-05-10T07:51:29.780Z [3ac15224] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection
>   :get()                     Error: Object with ID
>   'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ResetBusinessNetwork' in
>   collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
>   2018-05-10T07:51:29.787Z [3ac15224] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection
>   :get()                     Error: Object with ID
>   'Transaction:org.hyperledger.composer.system.SetLogLevel' in
>   collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist
>   2018-05-10T07:51:29.794Z [3ac15224] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection
>   :get()                     Error: Object with ID
>   'Participant:blil.security.FilePartic' in collection with ID
>   '$sysregistries' does not exist 2018-05-10T07:51:29.804Z [3ac15224]
>   ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error:
>   Object with ID 'Transaction:blil.security.addToLogFile' in collection
>   with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist 2018-05-10T07:51:29.815Z
>   [3ac15224] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()
>   Error: Object with ID 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin'
>   in collection with ID
>   'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' does not
>   exist 2018-05-10T07:51:29.815Z [3ac15224] ERROR    :Resolver
>   :resolveRelationship()     Failed to resolve relationship
>   {"stack":["{Error}Object with ID
>   'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in collection with ID
>   'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' does not
>   exist Error: Object with ID
>   'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in collection with ID
>   'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' does not
>   exist","    at NodeDataCollection.get
>   (/usr/local/src/node_modules/composer-runtime-hlfv1/lib/nodedatacollection.js:73:28)","
>   at ","    at process._tickCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)"]} 2018-05-10T07:51:29.816Z
>   [3ac15224] INFO     :IdentityManager          :()
>   Binding in the tx names and impl 2018-05-10T07:51:29.822Z [3ac15224]
>   INFO     :EngineTransactions       :createHistorianRecord()   created
>   historian record 2018-05-10T07:51:29.828Z [3ac15224] ERROR
>   :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object
>   with ID 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in collection
>   with ID 'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry'
>   does not exist 2018-05-10T07:51:29.828Z [3ac15224] ERROR    :Resolver 
>   :resolveRelationship()     Failed to resolve relationship
>   {"stack":["{Error}Object with ID
>   'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in collection with ID
>   'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' does not
>   exist Error: Object with ID
>   'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in collection with ID
>   'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' does not
>   exist","    at NodeDataCollection.get
>   (/usr/local/src/node_modules/composer-runtime-hlfv1/lib/nodedatacollection.js:73:28)","
>   at ","    at process._tickCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)"]} 2018-05-10T07:51:29.834Z
>   [3ac15224] INFO     :EngineTransactions       :createHistorianRecord()
>   created historian record 2018-05-10T07:51:29.840Z [3ac15224] ERROR
>   :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object
>   with ID 'alice-org1' in collection with ID
>   'Participant:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' does not
>   exist 2018-05-10T07:51:29.840Z [3ac15224] ERROR    :Resolver
>   :resolveRelationship()     Failed to resolve relationship
>   {"stack":["{Error}Object with ID 'alice-org1' in collection with ID
>   'Participant:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' does not
>   exist Error: Object with ID 'alice-org1' in collection with ID
>   'Participant:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' does not
>   exist","    at NodeDataCollection.get
>   (/usr/local/src/node_modules/composer-runtime-hlfv1/lib/nodedatacollection.js:73:28)","
>   at ","    at process._tickCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)"]} 2018-05-10T07:51:29.849Z
>   [3ac15224] INFO     :EngineTransactions       :createHistorianRecord()
>   created historian record 2018-05-10T07:51:29.854Z [3ac15224] ERROR
>   :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object
>   with ID 'bob-org2' in collection with ID
>   'Participant:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' does not
>   exist 2018-05-10T07:51:29.854Z [3ac15224] ERROR    :Resolver
>   :resolveRelationship()     Failed to resolve relationship
>   {"stack":["{Error}Object with ID 'bob-org2' in collection with ID
>   'Participant:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' does not
>   exist Error: Object with ID 'bob-org2' in collection with ID
>   'Participant:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' does not
>   exist","    at NodeDataCollection.get
>   (/usr/local/src/node_modules/composer-runtime-hlfv1/lib/nodedatacollection.js:73:28)","
>   at ","    at process._tickCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)"]} 2018-05-10T07:51:29.863Z
>   [3ac15224] INFO     :EngineTransactions       :createHistorianRecord()
>   created historian record 2018-05-10T07:51:29.871Z [3ac15224] ERROR
>   :NodeDataCollection       :get()                     Error: Object
>   with ID 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in collection
>   with ID 'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry'
>   does not exist 2018-05-10T07:51:29.871Z [3ac15224] ERROR    :Resolver 
>   :resolveRelationship()     Failed to resolve relationship
>   {"stack":["{Error}Object with ID
>   'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in collection with ID
>   'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' does not
>   exist Error: Object with ID
>   'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in collection with ID
>   'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' does not
>   exist","    at NodeDataCollection.get
>   (/usr/local/src/node_modules/composer-runtime-hlfv1/lib/nodedatacollection.js:73:28)","
>   at ","    at process._tickCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)"]} 2018-05-10T07:51:29.874Z
>   [3ac15224] ERROR    :NodeDataCollection       :get()
>   Error: Object with ID 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin'
>   in collection with ID
>   'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' does not
>   exist 2018-05-10T07:51:29.874Z [3ac15224] ERROR    :Resolver
>   :resolveRelationship()     Failed to resolve relationship
>   {"stack":["{Error}Object with ID
>   'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in collection with ID
>   'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' does not
>   exist Error: Object with ID
>   'org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin' in collection with ID
>   'Asset:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry' does not
>   exist","    at NodeDataCollection.get
>   (/usr/local/src/node_modules/composer-runtime-hlfv1/lib/nodedatacollection.js:73:28)","
>   at ","    at process._tickCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)"]} 2018-05-10T07:51:29.878Z
>   [3ac15224] INFO     :EngineTransactions       :createHistorianRecord()
>   created historian record

Comment: the REST server should work for the 'alice' and 'bob' cards in a multi-org setup.  Can you run `composer network ping` and `composer network list` using alice's and bob's cards ?

Comment: Using alice (form machine 1, where I started the network) I can, but using bob (from the other machine) I cannot and get the same error as above. I believe it is something in the card configuration or peer generation, but I can't seem to figure it out

Comment: OK - so the REST command is masking a different problem :-)   I would check the logs of the Peers containers for the time/date that you did the composer network start command.

Comment: In the peer containers themselves I don't see errors (i.e. peer0.org1.example.com and peer0.org2.example.com) However in the container  peer0.org1.example.com-peer0.org1.example.com-network-0.0.1-2a8bd3a915a964e62c2eadc505d59ccddae8a0cb5c40266c923b712ee160b352 there are many. I am posting them in an edited version of the question. Note however that the network start command says it ran successfully...

Comment: I suspect the main error is the first one : `E0510 07:49:44.580450529 17 ssl_transport_security.cc:238] Could not get common name of subject from certificate.` which leads to all the others....

Comment: yes, it is, in particular related to the LSCC error. For the `sysregistrie` errors, it might be that you are missing the essential System & Network ACLs (for a participant, even an admin participant, to read the system namespace and registries - see https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/acl_language or the sample networks for examples)

Comment: I used the same ACL as the samples (copied what I have here). When I do the commands with the same bna file where everything is on a single machine, it works (even though the ssl error still shows up, but none of the others).
`rule Default {
    description: "Allow all participants access to all resources"
    participant: "ANY"
    operation: ALL
    resource: "blil.security.*"
    action: ALLOW
}

rule SystemACL {
  description:  "System ACL to permit all access"
  participant: "ANY"
  operation: ALL
  resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.**"
  action: ALLOW
}`

Comment: I now see that here on the second line of the above logs it says: ` start-network "--peer.address" "10.0.0.249:7052"' whereas in the single machine 10.0.0.249 was replaced with peer0.org1.example.com. Could this be causing the issue? @PaulO'Mahony

Comment: I am also confused the composer cards for my setup. I have two connection profiles, one for each organization (and these have differences in the urls for the services since peer for org1 is on the same machine as the orderer etc. (that one has localhost for services on the same machine and the ip address of the second machine for the other services while for org2 profileit is reversed.) I then install the network on each machine  using the relevant card, request admin identity for each org, and copy the file for the second admin to the machine where I start the network. Does this sound right?

Comment: yes, install using a Peer Admin card (composer network install) on peer(s) in each Org. See Step Seven *onwards* in the multi-Org on -tutorial to understand minimally what you need to do. Your CA servers will also have to issue the admin certs - so that you can request them (as shown in the tutorial). Peer Admin card will have a different connection.json config from the Peer Admin card used to do a composer network start,  as the latter needs to know about Peers in all Orgs. On --peer.address, yes I say its contributing, your machines and docker containers will need to resolve by FQ name.

Comment: The error you are receiving is fabric saying that the chaincode container it is trying to access has a different fingerprint to the one that responds ok and this is not acceptable. What isn't clear is how this type of scenario manifests itself. Do you get the problem every time you install and start a new business network ?

Comment: I followed this tutorial: https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/hyperledger-fabric-on-multiple-hosts-a33b08ef24f and tried to adapt it for composer. The example chaincode execution in the article worked for me, but something in composer is not. I see that the chaincode container on the second peer (i.e. not the one where I issued network start) never gets started too...

Comment: @david_k If I follow the example in the tutorial for the simple chaincode I am able to instantiate on peer0.org1.example.com, query on peer0.org2.example.com, and invoke on peer0.org1.example.com.  I also see chaincode containers on both peers with the simple chaincode example (same as the one from BYFN on HLF). In other words, this problem only seems to happen with composer....

Comment: Have you tried any of the basic fabric node.js samples on your setup to see if they work or have similar problems ? This isn't necessarily a problem with Composer, but it's trying to understand why fabric thinks there is a fingerprint mismatch on your other organisation. I assume you install the exact same BNA file onto the peers of each organisation ?

Comment: I just noticed that I had different version of composer on my two computers. One was 0.19.4 and the other was 0.19.0. I am updating both now to 0.19.5 and will report if this solves the issue for me.

Comment: If I move into the peers to the director /var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes and do a md5sum on my network for each of the 2 peers I see a difference still. For the chaincode that works for me the md5sum is the sum in both peers for the chaincode. I see this post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44909489/chaincode-fingerprint-does-not-match-when-querying-from-other-peer suggesting perhaps the GOPATH could be the issue, but I don't seem to have GOPATH set in other peer, so I would think it should still be the same md5sum.

Comment: Well now at least the chaincode container has started on the second peer. It seems the issue was the different versions of composer. Even though I still see different md5sum values for the network on the different peers....

Comment: @david_k, sorry I missed your question, but yet I copy the bna file installed on one peer to the other prior to installing (the two bna files on the peers to have the same md5sum also).

Comment: Ok, so I was assuming you were using the same level of composer for both installs. A different level of cli would install a different version of the chaincode. That's due to the CLI having to inject what version of composer runtime to associate with the bna if not explicitly declared and by doing so you have differing chaincode installs if the CLI versions are different. That's really useful to know and something we should look at improving the documentation around. Thanks

Comment: I should note that the chaincode on the peers still seem to have different md5sum though. Also my problem came from downloading the using the installs/script on the tutorial page as I didn't realize the versions had changed.... Sorry to continue hassling you, but have you also had a chance to see the below error or should I start a new thread for it? For now I'm waiting since I think it may still be a version issue, though I don't see how.

Answer (score 0):

Now I managed to get past the previous issue by rectifying my composer versions to both be 0.19.5 as opposed to being different 0.19.x .

Comment: We're you able to make composer work with multiple hosts? I'm having issue similar to yours...

Comment: Unfortunately not. I think it is something in the setting of the composer connection profiles because the fabric works.

Comment: Personally I gave up on Composer... My attention now is on this repo https://github.com/olegabu/fabric-starter. Did you find any other starter project...