# failed to get chaincode container info for mycc:1.0 while executing peer chaincode query for multi machine

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, chaincode

I am trying to setup a hyperledger network with 2 orgs running on 2 different physical machine. So machine 1 has orderer, peer0.org1, peer1.org1, ca-org1, couchdb1, couchdb2 and cli containers. Machine 2 has peer0.org2, peer1.org2, ca-org2, couchdb3, couchdb4 and cli container.

Below is the docker-compose-org1.yaml file -

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  orderer.example.com:
  peer0.org1.example.com:
  peer1.org1.example.com:

networks:
  byfn:

services:
  ca0.example.com:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org1
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/65cc7012f64e12926807f9b731d3f4dbbda27dc577cb5a6afdb3730fcf53c48c_sk
    ports:
      - '7054:7054'
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/65cc7012f64e12926807f9b731d3f4dbbda27dc577cb5a6afdb3730fcf53c48c_sk -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca0.example.com
    extra_hosts:
      - "peer0.org2.example.com:10.160.151.114"
      - "peer1.org2.example.com:10.160.151.114"      
      - "ca1.example.com:10.160.151.114"
    networks:
      - byfn


  orderer.example.com:
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=INFO
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      # enabled TLS
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: orderer
    volumes:
      - ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
      - orderer.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    extra_hosts:
      - "peer0.org2.example.com:10.160.151.114"
      - "peer1.org2.example.com:10.160.151.114"
      - "ca1.example.com:10.160.151.114"
    ports:
      - 7050:7050
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_byfn
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb0:5984
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
      - peer0.org1.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    extra_hosts:
      - "peer0.org2.example.com:10.160.151.114"
      - "peer1.org2.example.com:10.160.151.114"
      - "ca1.example.com:10.160.151.114"
    command: peer node start
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7053:7053
    depends_on:
      - couchdb0
    networks:
      - byfn

  couchdb0:
    container_name: couchdb0
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    ports:
      - '5984:5984'
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer1.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_byfn
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb1:5984
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
      - peer1.org1.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    extra_hosts:
      - "peer0.org2.example.com:10.160.151.114"
      - "peer1.org2.example.com:10.160.151.114"
      - "ca1.example.com:10.160.151.114"
    command: peer node start
    ports:
      - 8051:7051
      - 8053:7053
    depends_on:
      - couchdb1
    networks:
      - byfn

  couchdb1:
    container_name: couchdb1
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    ports:
      - '6984:5984'
    networks:
      - byfn


  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:$IMAGE_TAG
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      #- CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer

    extra_hosts:
      - "peer0.org2.example.com:10.160.151.114"
      - "peer1.org2.example.com:10.160.151.114"
      - "ca1.example.com:10.160.151.114"

    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode
      - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
      - ./scripts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/scripts/
      - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
    depends_on:
      - orderer.example.com
      - peer0.org1.example.com
      - peer1.org1.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn
```

docker-compose-org2.yaml file -

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  peer0.org2.example.com:
  peer1.org2.example.com:

networks:
  byfn:

services:
  ca1.example.com:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org2
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/16acd23be9bbaf215828ddb410074828ce2b87ab68dff5976725b36f439f8c47_sk
    ports:
      - '7054:7054'
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/16acd23be9bbaf215828ddb410074828ce2b87ab68dff5976725b36f439f8c47_sk -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca0.example.com
    extra_hosts:
      - 'peer0.org1.example.com:10.160.151.121'
      - 'peer1.org1.example.com:10.160.151.121'
      - 'ca0.example.com:10.160.151.121'
      - 'orderer.example.com:10.160.151.121'
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer0.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org2.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org2.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_byfn
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb2:5984
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
      - peer0.org2.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production

    extra_hosts:
      - 'peer0.org1.example.com:10.160.151.121'
      - 'peer1.org1.example.com:10.160.151.121'
      - 'ca0.example.com:10.160.151.121'
      - 'orderer.example.com:10.160.151.121'

    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start
    ports:
      - 9051:7051
      - 9053:7053
    depends_on:
      - couchdb2
    networks:
      - byfn

  couchdb2:
    container_name: couchdb2
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    ports:
      - '7984:5984'
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer1.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org2.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org2.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_byfn
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb3:5984
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer1.org2.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer1.org2.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
      - peer1.org2.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production

    extra_hosts:
      - 'peer0.org1.example.com:10.160.151.121'
      - 'peer1.org1.example.com:10.160.151.121'
      - 'ca0.example.com:10.160.151.121'
      - 'orderer.example.com:10.160.151.121'

    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start
    ports:
      - 10051:7051
      - 10053:7053
    depends_on:
      - couchdb3
    networks:
      - byfn

  couchdb3:
    container_name: couchdb3
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    ports:
      - '8984:5984'
    networks:
      - byfn

  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:latest
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      #- CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer

    extra_hosts:
      - 'peer0.org1.example.com:10.160.151.121'
      - 'peer1.org1.example.com:10.160.151.121'
      - 'ca0.example.com:10.160.151.121'
      - 'orderer.example.com:10.160.151.121'

    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ./chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode
      - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
      - ./scripts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/scripts/
      - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
    depends_on:
      - peer0.org2.example.com
      - peer1.org2.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn
```

As you can see I am using "extra_hosts" to connect to the docker container in other machine. 
This way I am able to create channel from one machine and join the channel for both peers from that machine. In the other machine I fetched the same channel config and join the same channel for both peers. 
I checked that all 4 peers in both machines have joined the same channel by below command -

```
peer channel list
peer channel getinfo -c mychannel
```

Now from machine 1 I have installed and instantiated chaincode. This is working fine. Used below commands to install and instantiate -

```
peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.0 -l golang -p github.com/chaincode/chaincode_example02/go/
```

```
peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls true --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C mychannel -n mycc -l golang -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":["init","a","100","b","200"]}' -P "AND ('Org1MSP.peer','Org2MSP.peer')"
```

If I query the chaincode from the same machine it is working fine and I am getting proper result.

```
peer chaincode query -C mychannel -n mycc -c '{"Args":["query","a"]}'
```

But when I am executing the same chaincode query command from different machine it is giving below error -

> Error: endorsement failure during query. response: status:500 message:"failed to execute transaction 2444b829db1485ad097b2e11442d65cb36f02de1c6a3f3372ad53594af4d1a4d: [channel mychannel] failed to get chaincode container info for mycc:1.0: could not get chaincode code: chaincode fingerprint mismatch: data mismatch"

I can see the hyperledger fabric is syncing all peers properly in both machines. Because when I run `peer channel getinfo -c mychannel` I can match the currentBlockHash, previousBlockHash and height value for all 4 peers. I am just not able to execute the `peer chaincode query` command from the other machine.

When I run `peer chaincode instantiate` command I can see a new docker container is created in machine 1 which is for running chaincode. But there is no such container in machine 2. 
Am I missing any configuration here so that the chaincode container created on machine 1 can be accessed from machine 2?

---

New findings:
I have installed chaincode on all 4 peers in both machines by running `peer chaincode install` command from the CLI container. I have two CLI container running in two machines.

When I run the command `peer chaincode list --installed`. In machine 1 I get result like below

> Name: mycc, Version: 1.0, Path: github.com/chaincode/chaincode_example02/go/, Id: 333a19b11063d0ade7be691f9f22c04ad369baba15660f7ae9511fd1a6488209

When I run the same command in machine 2. The result is same except the `Id` value is different. But I also found that the `Id` value is same for both peers on same machine. Probably that's why I am able to execute the chaincode query from both peers on same machine. But not able to run it from other machine. Looks like that's the root cause of this problem.

Comment: Ideally, if all the docker peers on both machines are connected to each other then one cli container(running on any machine) should be able to create and install chain code to all the peers. All you need to do is copy genesis and configtx files to all peers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure out the problem ultimately so posting an answer here. The problem was that when I was installed the chaincode from two different machine the chaincode `Id` was different. Previously I was using the command `peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.0 -l golang -p github.com/chaincode/chaincode_example02/go/` to install the chaincode seperately on two machines. So when I do `peer chaincode list --installed` it was showing the `Id` value as different.

I was able to solve it using slightly a different approach. First created chaincode package using the command `peer chaincode package ccpack.out -n mycc -l golang -p github.com/chaincode/chaincode_example02/go/ -v 1.0`. It will generate a file `ccpack.out`. Moved this file physically from one machine to another. Then installed the same package file in both machines using the command `peer chaincode install ccpack.out`. In that way the chaincode `Id` remains same and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the ChainCode on your other peer as well?

> When I run peer chaincode instantiate command I can see a new docker container is created in machine 1 which is for running chaincode. But there is no such container in machine 2. Am I missing any configuration here so that the chaincode container created on machine 1 can be accessed from machine 2?

This is as intended. Taken from the docs: "**chaincode container is not started for a peer until an init or traditional transaction - read/write - is performed against that chaincode**"

So simply identify as your other peer, install the chaincode the same way you did for the first one and then you can make a call (query or invoke doesnt matter) with that peer and you see that the chaincode-container will come up.

Comment: I ran `peer chaincode install` command in both machines. Both machine have a cli(fabric-tools) container. I am using those two containers to run the commands.

Comment: One more thing I found that when I run `peer chaincode list --installed` command in machine 1 I get below result `Name: mycc, Version: 1.0, Path: github.com/chaincode/chaincode_example02/go/, Id: 333a19b11063d0ade7be691f9f22c04ad369baba15660f7ae9511fd1a6488209`. I run the same command is machine 2. The `Id` value is different in machine 2. Is that the problem here? Interestingly both peers in same machine have same `Id` for the chaincode.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. For me the chaincode file was different. Copying the whole chaincode folder to another machine at the same location worked for me.
Take a look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57628211/3750798

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Please consult [answer] to read more about how to answer questions